# Creating PDF-forms with TeX/LaTeX?

Tags: lyx, pdf, forms

I've been looking at the creation of PDF-forms - ie. PDF-documents with boxes where the user may fill in information like name and phonenumber or simply check a box to confirm something - in LibreOffice.

Is it possible to make such "fill-in-able" PDF-documents with TeX or LaTeX?  If it's possible, which extra (unusual?) packages will I need?

I'm thinking of rather simple forms... perhaps with textbox or textline to fill-in things like name or address, and perhaps check-and/or radio-boxes for confirming or choose between multipple-choice options.

Bonus question...  Is it possible to design such forms with LyX?

Comment: You have to use the `hyperref` package by H. Oberdiek. The elements to be filled are described in the corresponding manual. Filling is possible, however, in order to save the input with the `pdf`, you have to use the professional Adobe Acrobat, which permits extended (Adobe Reader) facilities.

Comment: I would guess that writing the code in ERTs is necessary to do this in LyX, I don't think there is support added in the GUI.